# Convergence in Probability, a question

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

Supposing $X_{t_i}$ is a real-valued stochastic process defined for $i=1,\ldots, N$, where $N=N_n\rightarrow\infty$, and $a_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, I am trying to see if the following holds:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}(X^2_{t_i}-a_n^2)=o_p(a_n)\tag{Result}
\end{equation}
when we have
\begin{equation}
\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\frac{X_{t_i}^2}{a_n^2}\overset{p}\rightarrow c\tag{$*$}
\end{equation}
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Open to amend the condition ($*$) if necessary.

---

**Some thoughts**: obviously, since we have

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N(X_{t_i}^2-a_n^2)}{a_n}\\
\qquad&\leq N\cdot \max_{1\leq i\leq N}\left(\frac{X_{t_i}^2-a_n^2}{a_n}\right)=Na_n\cdot \max_{1\leq i\leq N}\left(\frac{X_{t_i}^2-a_n^2}{a_n^2}\right)\\
&\leq Na_n\cdot \max_{1\leq i\leq N}\left(\frac{X_{t_i}^2}{a_n^2}-1\right),
\end{align*}
if $c=1$ and $N=O(a_n^{-1})$, we have the desired result by ($*$).

But I am not sure if we really need to restrict $c=1$. Also, I am looking for a way to relax $N=O(a_n^{-1})$ as well. Perhaps the bounds above in my solution is not tight enough somehow

Comment: Counter-example: $N_n=n, a_n=n^{-1/2}, c=2, X_{in}=\sqrt 2 a_n$.

Comment: Sorry, X does not depend on n. Edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Without any further assumptions on $X_{t_i}$, I believe your result perhaps cannot be further relaxed. The maximal inequality bound in your solution should be tight, as one can take $X_{t_i} \equiv X$ such that $X^2/a_n^2\overset{p}{\to} c$ which attains the equality. If $c\neq 1$,  we have $(X^2/a_n^2-1)  =(X^2/a_n^2-c)+(c-1)$, but the latter term does not vanish.

Comment: I agree, thanks Fred :)